# How to install apache 2.4.12 from source onto Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, pcre, apr

I tried to install Apache 2.4.12 from the installation page on the [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html) website but to no avail. It said that I needed to install APR, APR-Util and Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions Library (PCRE). So I downloaded them and installed them, so I thought it still gave me an error I think that I am compiling something wrong so if someone could lead me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you just use:

sudo apt-get install apache2

Cheers,

Nioidai

Answer (score 0):

**Please note that you should always install the latest version of a software for more security. I suggest you to install Apache from Ubuntu's apt package manager 'if you are on a production server'. Installing it from source on a local environment doesn't matter.**
I've also been trying to do this lately.
Please follow this for the instructions of installing it, by me, with a bit more explanation.
Hope it helps.
To be clean, follow the same steps:
1) Go to http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi
2) Right click and copy the link of the link like 'Source: httpd-2.4.41.tar.gz'
3) Go to the terminal, and enter the following commands one by one and hit enter for no confusion:

a.

```
cd /usr/local/src
```

b.

```
sudo wget -O- <download-link> | tar -zxf -
```

c.

```
sudo apt install libnghttp2 libpcre3 libssl build-essential -y
```

d. Go to http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi and copy the link like 'Unix Source: apr-1.7.0.tar.gz'

```
sudo wget -O- <apr-download-link> | tar -zxf -
```

e. Go to http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi and copy the link like 'Unix Source: apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz'

```
sudo wget -O- <apr-util-download-link> | tar -zxf -
```

f.

```
sudo mv apr-<apr-version> httpd-<apache-version>/srclib/apr
```

g.

```
sudo mv apr-util-<apr-util-version> httpd-<apache-version>/srclib/apr-util
```

h.

```
cd httpd-<apache-version>
```

i. According to me, this configuration is better than any other. The **--prefix** is where apache is installed.

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-mods-shared="reallyall" --enable-mpms-shared="all"
```

j.

```
sudo make
```

k.

```
sudo make install
```

These directories could be altered using the Step **'i'**
The apache directory is /usr/local/apache2.
The apache conf directory is /usr/local/apache2/conf.
The apache main conf file is /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf.
For more info go to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html.
Thanks